# %% in sec2time() Python

Tags: python

In the `sec2time()` Python function provided by Lee he uses a syntax I'm struggling to understand:

```
pattern = '%%02d:%%02d:%%0%d.%df' % (n_msec+3, n_msec)
```

What is the `%%`here and how does it affect the outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%` in that string introduces replaceable parts as at the end `%d.%df`. If you want a % in the output you have to do something special, in this case use `%%`

After these substitustions the resulting pattern will look like:

```
'%02d:%02d:%0123.120f'
```

which, among other things an be used for further substitution.

In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations), at the bottem of the second table in that section, it states:

```
'%'        No argument is converted, results in a '%' character in the result.
```